# How to implement jCrypt java class in coldfusion?

Tags: java, coldfusion

I need `jCrypt` java class in my ColdFusion application to encrypt passwords. Here is the code that I'm trying to use:

```
<cfscript>
    cfobject( name="JCrypt", type="java", action="create", class="JCrypt" );
    enc_password = trim(JCrypt.crypt("kL","myPassTest123"));
</cfscript>
```

Once I run this code error occurred with this message:

```
Object Instantiation Exception.
Class not found: JCrypt
```

The message indicates that class is not found. I'm wondering how I can implement `jCrypt` in my ColdFusion application? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think jCrypt is a part of default ColdFusion classes. You'll need to download the jar file into the `cfusion/lib` directory. Then createobject using proper class path.

Comment: PS: encrypting passwords and keeping it in database is never a good idea.

Comment: @RRK Do you know where I can download jCrypt jar? Also, can you provide example on how to create object for that class? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know where we can find that or even which one of the google search results is the real jCrypt. Everything I can find is really old jar files in sourceforge.

Comment: @RRK That's the same issue I'm experiencing. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I think the one you are looking for is http://rforge.net/org/doc/org/rosuda/JRclient/jcrypt.html I am not sure though.

Comment: Also this seems to be terribly out dated library. If I were you, I would use alternative ColdFusion, function(s).

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/RoSuDA/JRclient/RF503

Comment: @RRK I wish this can be replaced. Unfortunately my hands are tied. I have to find the way to integrate jCrypt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be hesitant to use something like JCrypt that has little to no footprint on the Internet as the base for password encryption. The sourceforge page has a link to a homepage to no longer exists. You should be using BCrypt for password encryption.

https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-in-action-understanding-bcrypt/

Brad Wood has a great presentation on ColdFusion and BCrypt called ["Pass the Salt"](https://www.meetup.com/coldfusionmeetup/pages/29672758/Recordings_of_the_Online_ColdFusion_Meetup_-_2019/).

You can download a copy of JBcrypt here:

https://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/

Here's a ColdBox Module that can give you some idea of a CF implementation:

https://github.com/coldbox-modules/cbox-bcrypt

That repo has a copy of the JBcrypt.jar file and a CFC wrapper that you can just drop into your application.

https://github.com/coldbox-modules/cbox-bcrypt/blob/master/modules/bcrypt/models/BCrypt.cfc

This wrapper uses a Java Loader to to load the JAR if you can't just drop the file into the CF server's lib path.

```
oBcrypt = new path.to.Bcrypt();
password = "Password";
hashed = oBcrypt.hashPassword(password);
check = oBcrypt.checkPassword(password, hashed);
```

The `hashPassword()` function will save the salt and the encrypted password in a single string that you save in the database.

Comment: If not using ColdBox, here's a vanilla CFC https://github.com/tonyjunkes/BCryptCFC